# Can't access singleton instance from Swift framework

Tags: swift

Using Xcode 6.3, I created a very simple, contrived command line tool in Swift. It contains three modules.

The main module:

```
import Foundation

let displayer = ValueDisplayer()

displayer.displayValue()
```

A ValueDisplayer module:

```
import Foundation

class ValueDisplayer {
    func displayValue() {
        println("The value is \(ValueProvider.instance.value)")
    }
}
```

and a ValueProvider module:

```
import Foundation

public class ValueProvider {
    class var instance: ValueProvider {
        struct Static {
            static let instance = ValueProvider()
        }

        return Static.instance
    }

    var value: Int {
        return Int(arc4random())
    }
}
```

This all compiled and ran successfully. However, I then decided to convert the ValueProvider to a framework. I created a Cocoa Framework target, and moved the ValueProvider module into it instead of in the command line target. I modified the ValueDisplayer module to this:

```
import Foundation
import ValueProvider

class ValueDisplayer {
    func displayValue() {
        println("The value is \(ValueProvider.instance.value)")
    }
}
```

and configured the command line tool to link against the framework. Now I get the following compilation error in the ValueDisplayer module related to the println statement:

> Module 'ValueProvider' has no member named 'instance'

I'm confused as to why the code doesn't work anymore. I'm wondering if the ValueProvider class is not being qualified correctly anymore, only it is unclear how that should be done.

What is needed to allow the command line tool to compile by linking against the framework?

Comment: Stop using the word "module" to mean "file". They are not at all the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

`public` is "opt-in". It is not applied magically to members of a public entity; you must apply it explicitly to a member of a public entity if you want that member to be public as well. You made the class `ValueProvider` public but you did not make its class var `instance` public, so it is not visible from another module.

So, you would need to rewrite like this:

```
public class ValueProvider {
    public class var instance: ValueProvider {
        // ...
    }
    public var value: Int {
        // ...
    }
}
```

[And by the way, a file is not a module. A framework is a module. That is why you have to change your code when you move it from merely being in a separate file to being in a different framework.]

Comment: It might help you to read my book's discussion of privacy: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_privacy_2

Comment: Also mentioned in the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html): *"NOTE: Any internal implementation details of your framework can still use the default access level of internal, or can be marked as private if you want to hide them from other parts of the framework’s internal code. You need to mark an entity as public only if you want it to become part of your framework’s API."*

Comment: I tried making the instance class member public, and I got the same error

Comment: Did you also make `value` public, as I showed in my answer? Otherwise you can't refer to that either.

Comment: I made everything public. I was still getting the same error.

Comment: @TronThomas I'm sorry my answer wasn't sufficient; perhaps this has something to do with the fact that it's a command line tool? But then are you saying that my answer is also not _necessary_? In other words, if you keep your use of a framework, do things work if you _remove_ the `public` attributes that I suggested?

Comment: The problem with the singleton not working happened even when creating an iOS application, so it is not specific to a command line tool. You were right that things need to be public, however I had already tried making everything public before I posting here, and forgot to include that in the details which may have distracted people from focusing on the real problem.

Comment: So your question didn't ask the question you meant to ask? And does your answer give the answer you think is the right answer? I for one have yet to grasp what your answer even means. I have written Swift apps that include a framework and I didn't have to futz around with any header files in any build phases.

Answer (score 1):

I got program to build and run. What I had to do was go to the **Build Phases** for the framework and remove the generated header file from the **Headers** section. I don’t know why this makes things work. My understanding is that header is needed to help with Objective-C interaction. If the program had needed to  interact with Objective-C as well as Swift, I’m wondering how anyone could get things to work properly.